# YouTube Core Error Domain: Service Unavailable

Tags: python, flask, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a Python script that uses the YouTube API to add a video to a playlist that I created. Some of the time the function works, but other times, when I try to execute the request, I get this error message:
`googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 409 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&alt=json returned "The operation was aborted.". Details: "[{'domain': 'youtube.CoreErrorDomain', 'reason': 'SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE'}]">`
Why would it work only some of the time and most importantly, is it mine or YouTube's fault? If it is my fault, how can I fix it? Here is the function that I call:

```
def addSongToPlaylist(self, video_id, playlist_id): # Adds a song to the playlist given
    request = add_video_request=self.youtube_service.playlistItems().insert(
    part="snippet",
    body={
            'snippet': {
                 playlistId': playlist_id, 
                 'resourceId': {
                    'kind': 'youtube#video',
                    'videoId': video_id
                }
            }
        }
    )
    print(video_id)
    response = request.execute()
    return response
```

I've also printed the video_id to make sure that it is a valid id and it always is. Thanks to anyone who can help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on youtube sid, it might be temporarily unavailable, one solution would be to put a `retry` mechanism so that it can handle those service disturbance.
Here is how you could do it in your code:

```
import time
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

def addSongToPlaylist(self, video_id, playlist_id): # Adds a song to the playlist given
    max_retries = 5
    retry_count = 0
    backoff_time = 1  # In seconds

    while retry_count < max_retries:
        try:
            request = self.youtube_service.playlistItems().insert(
                part="snippet",
                body={
                    'snippet': {
                        'playlistId': playlist_id,
                        'resourceId': {
                            'kind': 'youtube#video',
                            'videoId': video_id
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
            print(video_id)
            response = request.execute()
            return response
        except HttpError as e:
            if e.resp.status == 409 and 'SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE' in str(e):
                retry_count += 1
                print(f"Attempt {retry_count} failed. Retrying in {backoff_time} seconds...")
                time.sleep(backoff_time)
                backoff_time *= 2  # Exponential backoff
            else:
                raise
    raise Exception("Failed to add the song to the playlist after multiple retries.")
```

Comment: Quick question. What does the 'raise' statement do in the else clause? I've seen the syntax 'raise Exception()' before, but I cant find anything on just raise on its own.

Comment: it re-raises the exception that was caught in the except block. it is for when you want to catch an exception, perform some additional logic,

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in the Javascript equivalent

```
const postYoutubeTrack = async (accessToken, singleResourceId, playlistId) => {
  let max_retries = 5;
  let retry_count = 0;
  let backoff_time = 1000; // In seconds

  while (retry_count < max_retries) {
    try {
      const bodyData = {
        snippet: {
          playlistId: playlistId,
          resourceId: {
            kind: singleResourceId.kind,
            videoId: singleResourceId.videoId,
          },
        },
      };

      const request = await fetch(`https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(bodyData),
      });

      // If the request is ok we return the valid json and update retry_count to exit loop.
      if (request.ok) {
        const response = await request.json();
        retry_count = 5;
        return response;
      }

      const failedResponse = await request.json();
      throw failedResponse;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err?.error);
      retry_count += 1;
      console.log(`Attempt ${retry_count} failed. Retrying in ${backoff_time} seconds...`);
      await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, backoff_time));
      backoff_time *= 2; // Exponential backoff
    }
  }
};
```